# I have a view not able to connect with my Login model through my controller

Tags: php

I have a view that is not showing up and not giving errors. I set it up as MVC with PDO. This is my first time trying to set it up this way I can do it all on one page but I am trying to set it up as an MVC with just PHPno framework.

I have tried adding few lines of code to resolve issue but I am stumped. Any assistance would be appreciated.

database

```
 <?php 
    class Database{
        protected $host = 'localhost';
        protected $dbname = 'login';
        protected $user = 'root';
        protected $password = '';

        public function openDbConnection()
        {
            $link = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->dbname", $this->user, $this->password);
            return $link;
        }

        public function closeDbConnection(&$link)
        {
            $link = null;
        }
    }
```

model

```
<?php
class LoginModel{
      protected $db;
      public function __construct($database)
      {
          $this->db = $database;
      }   

      public function getLogin()
      {
          $link = $this->db->openDbConnection();

                $query = "SELECT * FROM login_user WHERE username = :username AND password = :password";  
                $statement = $link->prepare($query);  
                $statement->execute(  
                     array(  
                          'username'     =>     $_POST["username"],  
                          'password'     =>     $_POST["password"]  
                     )  
                );  
                $count = $statement->rowCount();  
                if($count > 0)  
                {  
                     $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];  
                     header("location:login_success.php");  
                }  
                else  
                {  
                     $message = '<label>Wrong Data</label>';  
                }  
                $this->db->closeDbConnection($link);


                return $login;
           }  

 }  



 ?>
```

controller

```
<?php 
class Login{

    protected $model = '';

    public function __construct($model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $login = $this->model->getLogin();
        require 'view/login/login.php';
    }
}
?>
```

View

```
<?php  
 session_start(); 




 ?>  
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Login</title>  
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br />  
           <div class="container" style="width:500px;">  
                <?php  
                if(isset($message))  
                {  
                     echo '<label class="text-danger">'.$message.'</label>';  
                }  
                ?>  
                <h3 align="">Login to Admin Section</h3><br />  
                <form method="post">  
                     <label>Username</label>  
                     <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" />  
                     <br />  
                     <label>Password</label>  
                     <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" />  
                     <br />  
                     <input type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-info" value="Login" />  
                </form>  
           </div>  
           <br />  
      </body>  
 </html>
```

Comment: Your code suggests that you're storing the passwords in plain text. **Don't do that.** You should _always_ hash the passwords using [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and _only_ store the hashes. Then you can use [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to verify a password against a hash.

Comment: yes I know I am doing it in plain text first just for testing purposes

Answer (score 0):

Your view isn't doing anything PHP related besides dealing with `$message`. Also you are returning an undefined variable from `LoginModel@getLogin`; there is no `$login` variable defined in that method.

I am going to **guess** you mean to return `$message` from `LoginModel@getLogin`, which is the error message. Then you mean to set `$message` variable in `Login@index` so that your view will have `$message`.

```
// LoginModel

public function getLogin()
{
    ...
    return $message;
}

// Login

public function index()
{
    $message = $this->model->getLogin();
    require 'view/login/login.php';
}
```

You probably also don't want the `session_start()` call in the view but in the controller.

Comment: I am still trying to figure out the mistakes you mentioned.

Comment: @DGamer - You'r basically using the wrong variable name. You're mixing between `$login` and `$message` all over the place.

Comment: I have removed anything with login and used just message still don't get the page to display I need to figure how to get the errors to show in php

Comment: don't get what page to display?

Comment: the login view still error somewhere in the model just need to force error to display for me in php I tried activating error in the ini file no luck

Comment: the view and model are not connected ... have you checked your logs for the error?

Comment: got the error finally Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Login::__construct(), 0 passed in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\index.php on line 16 and exactly 1 expected in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\controller\Login.php:6 Stack trace: #0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\index.php(16): Login->__construct() #1 {main} thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\controller\Login.php on line 6

Comment: you also probably don't want the `session_start()` in the view ... how can your `getLogin` method save the username to the session if the session isn't started yet